# Derivation of a determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, polynomials, determinant

Suppose we have a square matrix $A(z)\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, z\in\mathbb{C}$. The determinant is defined as $det(A)(z)$, which is a polynomial.

Then we derive $det(A)(z)$ at $z$. Are there then any correlations or statements that could be made between $det(A)’(z)$ and $A$ itself or something like that?

I am trying to understand the meaning of $det(A)’(z)$ better.

Comment: Yes, it's a polynomial, with $n^2$ variables. Which concept of derivative do you have in mind? Is it the Fréchet derivative?

Comment: There’s a long article on matrix calculus on Wiki

Comment: What is the Frechet derivative? I thought just of the normal derivation of a polynomial.

Comment: I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763790/derivative-of-determinant).

Comment: Dietrich, the OP is asking a much simpler question, the matrix varies with a single complex parameter only.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry on [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) would be a good place to start.